# Convert byte[] buf[offset] to int16

Tags: c#

I'm getting a compile error

> "Unable to convert int to short".

Any ideas?

```
public Int16 GetInt16(byte[] buf, int offset)
{
    Int16 value = 0;

    value += buf[offset] << 8;

    return value;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to explicitly cast the result value += (Int16)(buf[offset] << 8);

Comment: Did you really mean to only use a single value from `buf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast or convert it. e.g.

```
value += Convert.ToInt16(buf[offset] << 8)
```

Comment: A cast would be simpler than a Convert.ToInt16 call here.

Answer (score 1):

Use BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, starting index). This will do the job for you and you do not have to reinvent the wheel. This also helps prevent accidently code errors (besides the starting index). (yes this is a little different solution to the question but does the same job in a more robust manner).

Documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16.aspx

Edit:

This will not work in your specific case because you use one byte. If you had the buffer and the two bytes would equal the int16 then you would have the correct data.

Comment: And as it happens, there's already a code error here - the code given only uses a single value from the byte array...

Comment: ahh good point. I did not realize that. The bit converter will then fail in this case.

Comment: No, I *suspect* BitConverter is the right approach here, and that the OP wanted to use two bytes. Unclear though.